# How can I convert a JSON string to an i64 using serde_json?

Tags: json, rust, serde

This is a sample JSON object I want to parse:

```js
{  
   "name":"John",
   "balance":"300000",
   "address":"Palo Alto, CA",
   "car":null
}
```

I've got the following struct using [`serde_json`](https://github.com/serde-rs/json) for parsing JSON:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Person {
    #[serde(alias = "name")]
    pub firstname: String,
    #[serde(alias = "balance")]
    pub amount: i64,
    pub address: String,
}
```

I want the `amount` field to be `i64` instead of `String` but it's a string in the JSON object.

Is there a [field attribute](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html) to enforce `String -> i64` conversion during parsing? Otherwise, I'll have to create a similar structure where `balance` is `i64` or tune my other project code to accept `balance` as `String` which is bad.